# What's the most fundamental derivative of multivariable functions?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

There are several derivatives of multivariable functions.  For instance, given a function $F: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^m$ there's

- the divergence $\nabla \cdot F$
- the curl $\nabla \times F$ (if $n=m=3$)
- the Jacobian $J_F(p)$
- the directional derivative $dF(p,v) = \lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{F(p+hv)-F(p)}{h}$

I'm wondering which of these is really *the* derivative of $F$.  I don't think it could be the divergence or curl because $(1)$ the curl isn't even defined except on $\Bbb R^3$ and $(2)$ when they're defined $(\nabla \cdot F)(p) = \operatorname{trace}(J_F(p))$ and $[(\nabla \times F)(p)]_k = \left[\frac12\big([J_F(p)]^T-J_F(p)\big)\right]_{ij}\varepsilon_{ijk}$.  So it seems that $J_F(p)$ is more fundamental.

But what about the directional derivative?  I don't even see have this relates to the Jacobian.  So which one (perhaps including some type of derivative I've never heard of) is more "fundamental"?  What is **the** derivative of a multivariable function?

Comment: Possibly wrong so read with caution: in integration on manifolds, we discover the "exterior derivative" operator $ d $, which is very fundamental and contains the divergence and curl as special cases. A separate idea is the Jacobian, which appears at the most basic level in calculus and is useful for approximating functions locally by linear functions. I think that the Jacobian and the exterior derivative are distinct concepts. For example, the exterior derivative is not used for local linear approximation. But correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Jacobian $J_F(p)$ (using your notation) is just the matrix representation of the linear map $dF(p,\cdot)$. So they both are "the most fundamental" first derivative (in the sense that divergence, curl and similar operators can be derived from them).

Comment: To OP: to confirm just notice that $\text d\mathbf F(\mathbf p,\mathbf x_i)=\frac{\partial \mathbf F(\mathbf p)}{\partial x^i}$ where $\mathbf x_i$ is the $i$th standard basis vector, which is exactly the $i$th column of $J_{\mathbf F}(\mathbf p)$.

Answer (score 2):

The Jacobian $J_F(p)$ contains all the data that all of the directional derivatives do. It tabulates the partial derivatives, which are directional derivatives in the directions $e_1, \dots, e_n$ (where $e_1, \dots, e_n$ is the standard basis of $\mathbb R^n$):
$$
J_F(p) = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial x_1}(p) & \cdots & \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial x_n}(p) \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\frac{\partial F_m}{\partial x_1}(p) & \cdots & \frac{\partial F_m}{\partial x_n}(p) \\
\end{bmatrix},
$$
where $F = (F_1, \dots, F_m)$,  $F_i : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ for $1 \leq i \leq m$. Any directional derivative $dF(p, v)$ (in your notation) is obtained from the partial derivatives by
$$
dF(p, v) = J_F(p) v.
$$
In particular, 
$$
dF(p, e_i) = J_F(p) e_i = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial x_i}(p) \\ \vdots \\ \frac{\partial F_m}{\partial x_i}(p) \end{bmatrix}.
$$
As others have said, divergence and curl can be derived from partial derivatives.

However, if you asked me what *the* derivative of $F$ is, I would say none of these. I'd say the derivative of $F$ at $p$ is the linear map $A : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ such that
$$
0 = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{F(p+h) - F(p) - A h}{\|h\|_\infty},
$$
if it exists, and I'd use the notation $A = DF(p)$.

The upshot here is that $DF(p)$ generalizes the nice properties of single-variable derivatives

1. Differentiability $\implies$ continuity
2. Composites of differentiable functions are differentiable,

while the directional derivatives (i.e., the Jacobian) do *not*. In fact, it can be the case that all directional derivatives exist at $p$ but $DF(p)$ as defined above does not exist. Moreover, if $DF(p)$ exists, its matrix is exactly $J_F(p)$. So I would call this *the* most general derivative of $F$.

This is an example (from Munkres's book *Analysis on Manifolds*, which I highly recommend) in which $F : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ has directional derivatives at $0$ in all directions, but $F$ is not differentiable, or even continuous, at $0$:
$$
F(x,y) = \begin{cases}
\frac{x^2 y}{x^4 + y^2} & (x,y) \neq 0 \\
0 & (x,y) = 0
\end{cases}.
$$

Comment: Maybe it should be said however that if $DF(p)$ exists then $[DF(p)](h) = dF(p,h)$.

Comment: Yes, I will add this! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Any function from $R^n$ to $R^m$, f(x), at $x= x_0$, can be written in the form $f(x)= A(x- x_0)+ \Delta$ where A is a linear transformation from $R^n$ to $R^m$ and $\frac{\Delta}{||x- x_0||}$ goes to 0 as $x$ goes to $x_0$.  Further, it can be shown that the linear transformation, A, is unique.  In the particular case that m= 1, A is a linear transformation from $R^n$ to $R$ which can be thought of as the dot product of an n dimensional vector with the n dimensional vector $x- x_0$.  That n-dimensional vector is $\nabla f$ or "grad f",  This precisely what florian said.

So the derivative, of a function from $R^n$ to $R$, at any point can be represented as an n dimensional vector which means that the derivative **function** is a function from $R^n$ to $R^n$ and so the second derivative at any point is linear function from $R^n$ to $R^n$ represented by an n by n matrix.  The third derivative at a point would be an "n by n by n" "matrix", etc.

Comment: I disagree with your statement about higher derivatives. The derivative ($A$ as you have) always has the same domain and target as the original function. Doing this successively should not change these.